# How to get Go's "block" profiler to work?

Tags: go, profiling

I am trying to enable Go's "block" profiler by adding the following code to my main function:

```
f, err := os.Create(profFile)
if err != nil {
    // Error handling
}

runtime.SetBlockProfileRate(1)
p := pprof.Lookup("block")
defer func() {
    err := p.WriteTo(f, 0)
    if err != nil {
        Logger.Error("Error writing block profile: %v", err)
    }
}()
```

I do see the profile file created after my application is run and I am trying to interpret the results by running the command:

```
$ go tool pprof --text <PROFILE_FILE> 
29.95mins of 29.95mins total (  100%)
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
 29.95mins   100%   100%  29.95mins   100%
```

I don't see any data on the block times. Is the code to generate block profile data correct? Or perhaps I need to use different options to "go tool"? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: You're missing the `[binary]` argument. The usage output from pprof: shows `pprof <format> [options] [binary] <source> ...`

Comment: Not that I care much, but why is the question being down voted? Whoever did it care to explain?

Comment: Questions that are easily answered by the docs tend to not go do well around here (the downvote tooltip starts with "this question does not show any research effort" after all), though I agree that it's strange that the binary argument is basically required, but the pprof tool lets you omit it.

Comment: I want to correct the impression that no research effort has been spent (as I said, I don't care about the votes). I spent hours finding a way to get block profiler to work. I am not the only one who finds it difficult. See here (https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14689). After all that time, I might have missed an optional argument from "pprof" usage info. Doesn't sound like big deal to me. But thanks for answering any way. It helped me and I did up vote it.

Answer (score 1):

As @JimB mentioned in the comment, the correct way of running "pprof" is as follows:

```
$ go tool pprof  --text <PATH_TO_BINARY> <PROFILE_FILE>
```

Comment: Why is the answer down voted? I added my own answer based on JimB's comment because he only provided the info as comment. I did this based on the guidance from meta stackexchange. What's wrong with this?